# Saving data on browser

Tags: http, cookies, browser, browser-cache

Can we save any data from the javascript. In my site I want to use RSA encryption but I want save privatekey into users browsers not to the server's databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LocalStorage` object can be used to store and load data on the client end.

Note though, the data it stores is temporary. If the user wipes their temporary files, the data will be lost. There is no way around this. If you need permanent storage, you'll need to send the data to the server and store it there.

Also note, the client can view and edit LocalStorage.